# Any brower gets connection reset on a specific site, while wget works

Tags: gnome, firefox, google-chrome

I cannot browser the http://nytimes.com website from any browser installed on my Linux Ubuntu (Chrome and Firefox), but I can download the landing page using `wget http://nytimes.com`

Already tried to clear cache but didn't solve. Any ideas?

Comment: what error you get ?

Comment: check your proxy settings in the browsers.

Comment: Tried disabling proxy and using system default, both didn't solve.
I get 'connection reset' error.